# Redux DevTools could not render

Tags: react-redux, redux-devtools

I am using `redux-devtools` with `redux-devtools-dock-monitor` and `redux-devtools-log-monitor`.

I followed documentation. However, in the console I receive this error:

```
index.js:1452 Redux DevTools could not render. 
You must pass the Redux store to <DevTools> either as a "store" prop 
or by wrapping it in a <Provider store={store}>.
```

Here is my Root component:

```
const Root = () => {
   return (
       <Provider store={store}>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello !!!</h1>
                <DevTools/>
            </div>
       </Provider>
   );
};

export default Root;
```

Additionally, I am getting this warning too:

```
redux-devtools@3.4.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-redux@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
```

I have used `redux-devtools-log-monitor` and `redux-devtools-dock-monitor` as monitors

Comment: Prefer this https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension

Answer (score 1):

In `react-redux@6`, the store is not passed via legacy React context and you should specify it explecitely via props like so:

```
<DevTools store={store}/>
```

Update 1: It was working for me because I had `react-redux@6` in main project, but `react-redux@5` for `redux-devtools` dependency. So if someone needs a quick workaround (you shouldn't include DevTools component in production anyway) till it will be supported, just do: `cd ./node_modules/redux-devtools && npm i react-redux@5`.

Update 2: `redux-devtools@3.5.0` was just published, which adds support for `react-redux@6`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the suggestion and now it gives another error (I'm using the DockMonitor). Ie this is my setup.

```
<DockMonitor toggleVisibilityKey='ctrl-h'
  changePositionKey='ctrl-q'
  changeMonitorKey='ctrl-m' >
  <LogMonitor />
</DockMonitor>


<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  <DevTools store={store} />
</Provider>
```

Produces the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Passing redux store in props has been removed and does not do anything. To use a custom Redux store for specific components,  create a custom React context with React.createContext(), and pass the context object to React-Redux's Provider and specific components like:  . You may also pass a {context : MyContext} option to connect

Comment: Yes, it's not supported. I edited my answer with a workaround.